# Desktop icons outside the monitor on second monitor (smaller one)

Tags: unity, nautilus, multiple-monitors, icons

I have a 24" and a 27" monitor connected to my notebook and arranged as you can see in the Display Settings window below.

[image: screenshot]

So the right (blue) monitor is higher than the left (green) one. My problem is that I have icons on my desktop. When I right-click on it and select <kbd>Organize desktop by name</kbd>, it places the icons like in the screenshot. You see that the first icon (red circle) is not entirely displayed.

I assume that Unity does not fit the desktop on both different monitors separately, but just uses a simple rectangle containing all monitors as desktop size. This fails, because my left monitor is slightly smaller in height and therefore there's a not displayed area of the desktop in the upper left quarter.

Here's the output of `xrandr --current`, in case this helps you to identify and solve the problem:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3520 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1366x768      59.64 +
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 connected primary 1600x900+0+159 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1400x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00* 
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.08    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
VGA1 connected 1920x1080+1600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.08    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Is there any fix for this, i.e. can I tell Unity (or is Nautilus responsible for that?) not to use that invisible part of the desktop for anything? The background image, panel and windows are all placed correctly, so why not the icons?

Answer (score 0):

You are right that it uses a simple rectangle containing all monitors. That is the best solution currently available for Linux, but it introduces multiple bugs (across the board, not just in the window manager) whenever your arrangement does not fill up the desktop with actual screen space. I have used multiple monitors on Linux for about 6 years now, and the only good workaround I have found is to use the same resolution on all my monitors (in your case 1920x1080 is the recommended resolution for both monitors).

Comment: But then they're scaled differently. I want that when I place a window on both screens, they have the same physical visible size.

Comment: Yes, it's annoying. What about rearranging them to line up the top of the screen instead of the bottom? That seems to work better sometimes. Or just upgrade the smaller screen like I did, so they are the same size.

Comment: They're physically placed in a way that both of their lower borders are aligned. So it makes no sense to use a different virtual position of the screen. Can't I somehow set the rectangle to lower dimensions? So that icons are only placed up to the height of the smaller screen. I would not care about whether there would be unused space on the bigger monitor then.

Comment: The nvidia driver can do that with the ViewPortOut setting, but I don't know if the standard drivers can do it. At any rate, that would make the upper part of the screen completely unusable.

Comment: Maybe this is why Kubuntu (KWin) puts its desktop icons in a movable, resizeable widget instead of directly on the desktop.

Comment: No, I want to just reduce the area where icons get placed. I don't want to have a black bar in the upper part of my larger screen. And it's just some Intel graphics anyway...